# UIImagePickerController not assigning image to uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to use the UIImagePickerController and save the image to a UIImageView but it the image isn't saved?

```
- (IBAction)handleAvatarTap:(id)sender {
DLog(@"");

UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage* original =[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// This is the line that sets the image but the original image assigned to it is still there?
[self.avatarImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:original.CGImage]];


}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `self.avatarImage` is not `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that avatarImage is init?

Something like:

```
self.avatarImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame] autorelease];
self.avatarImage.image = original;
```

Comment: Is original != nil when you set it?

Answer (score 0):

Set user interaction to enabled and it works now.

Comment: What does this have to do with whether the image view's image property is updated or not?

Comment: But the question has nothing to do with dismissing the view controller. Please read the question again. The issue is that the image view isn't being updated with the selected image.

Comment: I am the guy who posted the question and this answer. That was the only thing I changed and it works. It probably has to do with the fact I am locking down and unlocking edit capabilities.

Comment: Doh! Sorry. I didn't notice this answer and the original question are from the same person. I'll undo my down vote though this answer is really unclear as to how it solved the asked question. It may be clear to you but not anyone looking at this later.